# How to set focus on div-wrapped siblings with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Due to requirements beyond my control (no mouse), I need to be able to use the arrow keys (in addition to tab) to scroll up and down through a stack of buttons on a web page.

I figured out how to do it with buttons that are pure siblings, but if I wrap those buttons in divs (to stack them vertically), my jQuery selector no longer works.  I essentially need a selector for "my parent's next sibling's child".  I have beaten my head against the wall for hours and can't figure this out.

In the following example, if you set focus to one of the buttons on the bottom, the arrow keys will let you move between the buttons.  The top pair of buttons, however, are wrapped in divs and the arrow keys won't work there.

Help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/button/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <div>
                <p> 
                    This doesn't work with up/down arrow keys:
                    <div><button id="textButton1" tabIndex="0">Button 1</button></div>                                 
                    <div><button id="textButton2" tabIndex="0">Button 2</button></div>
                </p>  
                  
                <p>
                    But this does:
                    <button id="textButton3" tabIndex="0">Button 3</button>                                           
                    <button id="textButton4" tabIndex="0">Button 4</button>                  
                </p>
            </div>
          
            <script>                    
                $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#textButton1").kendoButton();
                     $("#textButton2").kendoButton();
                     $("#textButton3").kendoButton();
                     $("#textButton4").kendoButton();
                     $(".k-button").width(350);
                     $(".k-button:first").focus();                
                });
              
                document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) 
                {
                    const key = event.key;
                    switch (key) 
                    {
                        case "ArrowDown":   
                            //alert('Down');
                            $(".k-button:focus").next().focus(); 
                            break;
                        case "ArrowUp":   
                            //alert('Up');
                            $(".k-button:focus").prev().focus(); 
                            break;
                    }
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                .demo-section p {
                    margin: 0 0 30px;
                    line-height: 50px;
                }               
                .k-button {
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }
                 
              .k-button .k-icon {
                   float: right;
                   margin: 2px;
                }
            </style>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can easily move between your buttons with the TAB key (forward) and Shilft+TAB (backward) (??)

Comment: I know.  It is a business requirement that the arrow keys do the same thing.  I didn't make the rules...

Answer (score 1):

as you are working with ID's I made this example you can try it.

I didn't work with next and previous but I added a data-key to each button.

hope it helps you

```js
                
              $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#textButton1").kendoButton();
                   $("#textButton2").kendoButton();
                   $("#textButton3").kendoButton();
                   $("#textButton4").kendoButton();
                   $(".k-button").width(350);
                   $(".k-button:first").focus();                
                });
              
              document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) 
              {
                const key = event.key;
                switch (key) 
                  {
                   case "ArrowDown":   
                      indexKey = $(".k-button:focus").data('key')+1
                      $('#textButton'+indexKey).focus(); 
                          
                      break;
                      case "ArrowUp":   
                      indexKey = $(".k-button:focus").data('key')-1
                      $('#textButton'+indexKey).focus(); 
                        
                      break;
              }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/button/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <div>
                    <p> 
     This doesn't work with up/down arrow keys:
     
                      <div><button id="textButton1" data-key='1' tabIndex="0">Button 1</button></div>                                 
       <div><button id="textButton2" data-key='2' tabIndex="0">Button 2</button></div>
                    </p>  
                  
                    <p>
      But this does:
     
                        <button id="textButton3" data-key='3' tabIndex="0">Button 3</button>                                           
      <button id="textButton4" data-key='4' tabIndex="0">Button 4</button>                  
                   </p>
                  
                    
                </div>

            <style>
                .demo-section p {
                    margin: 0 0 30px;
                    line-height: 50px;
                }               
                .k-button {
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }
                 
              .k-button .k-icon {
                   float: right;
                   margin: 2px;
                }
            </style>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `next()` or `prev()` only works with siblings. For your case, you could use button indexes instead...

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

    const key = event.key;

    var lastButtonIndex = $(".k-button").length - 1;
    var focusedButtonIndex = $(".k-button").index($(".k-button:focus"));

    switch (key) {
        case "ArrowDown":
            if (focusedButtonIndex < lastButtonIndex)
                $(".k-button").eq(focusedButtonIndex+1).focus();
            break;
        case "ArrowUp":
            if (focusedButtonIndex > 0)
                $(".k-button").eq(focusedButtonIndex-1).focus();    
            break;
    }

});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: What is Stack Overflow etiquette for handling a situation where two people answer a question with usable solutions?  I used your code but the guy below answered first and his code also works.  His reputation is lower so I feel like I should throw him a bone.

Comment: Don’t worry, man! Just mark the one you select to solve your problem to help other people that will maybe check your question in the future. This points are not going to make us famous!! ;) Good to hear you solved your problem. Have a nice day and happy coding!